# Downloading multiple files using SSIS and C#

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a requirement to download multiple files using SSIS and C# as the scripting language. I have tried but the file is downloading with 0 bites and I get an error message "the remote server returned and error(0) bad request. Can anyone please assist.This is what I have tried so far.
I've pasted the code below.

```
public void Main()
{

    string url = (string)Dts.Variables["User::vlink"].Value;
    string path = (string)Dts.Variables["$Project::DownloadPath"].Value;
    string filenames = (string)Dts.Variables["User::vfilename"].Value;
    string docpath = path + "\\" + filenames;

    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }

    { 
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);

        client.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", " en-US");
        client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        client.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/plain");
        client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8";
        client.Headers.Add("Accept", " text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*");
        client.Headers.Add("UserAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0");
        client.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "application/x-gzip";
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Test", "Test@1234", "Test");
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileComplete);
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(Client_DownloadProgressChanged);

        client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, docpath);



        //while (client.IsBusy)
        //{
        //    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        //}


        //Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        //MessageBox.Show("Download Complete");
    }

}

private void Client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.BytesReceived + " " + e.ProgressPercentage);

}

void client_DownloadFileComplete(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Download Completed");
}


#region ScriptResults declaration
/// <summary>
/// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
/// result of the script.
/// 
/// This code was generated automatically.
/// </summary>
enum ScriptResults
{
    Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
    Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
};

#endregion
```

Comment: Change your password. You can't delete it because of track changes.

Comment: Did you try this?   https://www.google.com/search?q=the+remote+server+returned+an+error+(400)+bad+request&oq=the+remote+server+return&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l5.9859j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the file was downloading with 0 bites because the login page was blocking the script and the link was different once you login. The link was therefore not being passed correctly because after login, all the white spaces were being replaced "%" sign. So I had to replace all the white spaces with with the same.